# jquery Ajax call from view to controller method but not display the view returned that method in mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have given Ajax call from Index.cshtml view to PrintPreview method which is present in MasterList Controller and i have also passed parameters. The Index method also present in MasterList controller But while returning view from PrintPreview method call is going to PrintPreview.cshtml page but the page is not loading i.e not displaying in browser and Index.cshtml page displaying in browser please help.

```
$('#printbtn').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("PrintPreview", "MasterList")',                
        data: 
{ saleorderIdList: JSON.stringify(saleorder_id),
orderIdList:JSON.stringify(order_id) },

        });
});





public ActionResult PrintPreview(string saleorderIdList, string orderIdList)
{
    var locationIdOfLoginUser = Convert.ToInt32(Session["LocationId"]);
    ViewBag.loccationName = Session["LocationName"];
    ViewBag.locationType = Session["LocationType"];
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    IEnumerable<int> saleOrderIds = new int[] { };
    IEnumerable<int> orderIds = new int[] { };
    if (saleorderIdList != null)
    {
        saleOrderIds = serializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<int>>(saleorderIdList);
    }
    if (orderIdList != null)
    {
        orderIds = serializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<int>>(orderIdList);
    }
    MasterListService masterListService = new MasterListService();
    var ordercollection = masterListService.GetSelectedorders(locationIdOfLoginUser, saleOrderIds, orderIds);
    return View(ordercollection);

}
```

In above code i got both array  saleOrderIds and  orderIds
also in ordercollection i got List as expected for view

call is going to that PrintPreview View also in that view i got all list as i passed to that view but That PrintPreview.cshtml page is not displaying instead Index.cshtml page is displaying from where ajax call is passed

Comment: Ajax calls stay on the same page. If you want to render the view returned by `PrintPreview` then it needs to be `return PartialView(ordercollection);` and in the ajax `success:` callback, update the DOM. If thats not what you want, do a normal submit/post to a method and redirect.

Comment: Can you please suggest code example

Comment: What is it that you want to do? Stay on the same page or redirect to another view?

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is, you are calling a function and not doing anything with the return value. This is how your Ajax call should look like:

```
$('#printbtn').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("PrintPreview", "MasterList")',                
        data: 
{ saleorderIdList: JSON.stringify(saleorder_id),
orderIdList:JSON.stringify(order_id) },

onSuccess: function(response) {
    // THIS IS WHERE YOU DISPLAY THE RETURN CSHTML SOMEWHERE.  response RETURN VALUE IS NOTHING BUTH THE WHOLE CSHTML

      //you may do something like
  $('#mydiv').html(response);
  }

        });
});
```

Assuming that your url and backend code work ok, this will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

1) Your doing a Ajax Call which will never redirect, if you wan to redirect use form submit instead of ajax call.

2) Or If you still want to achieve with ajax call, use partial views to reload the ajax return data. Then your have to use return PartialView(ordercollection);

Like explained here [MVC4 Partial View With Ajax](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PartialView-and-Ajax-bb05c909)

Comment: But i have to pass two array list to that method

Comment: You can achieve that, With help of Ajax + Partial View Concept have a look at the link provided in answer

Comment: But if i use form submit how can i pass two array list to that method

Comment: In script 
jquery i got two arrays then how can that arrays to onclick event of print  button